# Is it possible to queue animations when using velocity.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, velocity.js

I'm working on a project with a push menu. When the content div slides over, the menu buttons have a little animation as they enter the screen. It doesn't take long or anything but the issue I'm having is if the user opens and closes the menu quickly a bunch of times in a row, the items on the list begin disappearing and reappearing in the wrong order. I think this is because the new animation calls are canceling out old ones and in general screwing up the order of things.

Ideally, I'd like the animations to always behave properly (i.e. if the menu is opening, clear all previous animations and play the opening animation only).

But I'd be satisfied if I could at least get each element to queue its animations properly so that the elements in the menu don't randomly disappear upon opening the menu.

Here is a fiddle of the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/9t10zr6m/1/

The top div is transparent because it normally has a background image. And also because I thought it might be easier to see the problem with the menu if you could see what was going on underneath the top div.

here is the relevant jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".expandable-content").on('click', function(){
    $(this).children(".internal-content").slideToggle();
});


$(".menu-button").on('click', function(){
    var position = $(".blue-box").css("left");
    if( position == "0px") {
        $(".blue-box").velocity({left: "250px"}, 500);
        $('.side-nav-link').finish();
        $('.side-nav-link').velocity('transition.slideUpIn', { stagger: 50 });
    } else {
        $(".blue-box").velocity({left: "0px"}, 500);
        $('.side-nav-link').finish();
        $('.side-nav-link').velocity('transition.slideDownOut', { stagger: 50 });
    }
});
```

});

and the relevant html:

```
<div class="blue-box">
        <h1>Julian Ptak</h1>
        <h2>Kempis Coder. Simplicity. Purity.</h2>
        <div class="menu-button"><img class="button-icon" src="img/menu-icon.png"><p class="button-text">Menu</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="red-box">
        <ul class="side-nav">
            <li class="side-nav-link"><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li class="side-nav-link"><a href="">Work</a></li>
            <li class="side-nav-link"><a href="">Hobbies</a></li>
            <li class="side-nav-link"><a href="">Writings</a></li>
            <li class="side-nav-link"><a href="">Code</a></li>
            <li class="side-nav-link"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

How do you make jQuery enqueue animations? Or only play the right animation for the right click and skipping all previous ones?

I tried .finish() and .stop() but neither seemed to fix my problem. Any ideas? Do those not work with velocity.js?

Answer (score 3):

Very long question!!
I don't get what you want, but according to some keywords in your question i will give you some Velocity features:
Velocity add animations to its queue by default!

```
$elm.velocity({ /* 1 */ },{});
$elm.velocity({ /* 2 */ },{});
```

in this example at the end of first animation second animation will start.

```
$elm.velocity({ /* 1 */ },{});
$elm.velocity({ /* 2 */ },{queue: false});
```

in this example both animations start together.

```
$elm.velocity('stop', true).velocity({ /* 1 */ },{});
```

in this example velocity('stop', true) clear the $elm queue then next animation immediately start.

Comment: `queue: false` great help! works like a dream, I have separate functions for the animations and have added this too animations i wish to happen at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful to use the delay param for velocity
for example :

```
  jQuery(function($){
var $pen = jQuery('#pen');
    $arrow1 = jQuery('#arrow1');
    $arrow2 = jQuery('#arrow2');
    $pdf = jQuery('#pdf');
    $screen = jQuery('#screen');
$pen
    .velocity("fadeIn", {
    duration: 1500,
    complete:function(elements){
        $arrow1.velocity("fadeIn", { duration: 1500});
    }
    });
});
```

The callback start after the end of the animation

in the meantime

```
  $pen.velocity("fadeIn", { duration: 1500 });
    $arrow1.velocity("fadeIn", { duration: 1500});
    });
```

the two animations start at the same time, so if you want a timeline, write a delay for start after the end of the first animation

```
   $pen.velocity("fadeIn", {
        duration: 1500
        });

    $arrow1.velocity("fadeIn", { duration: 1500,delay:1500});
    });
```

Nevermind with the ui Pack you've a great explanation here
[Ui pack sequence](http://julian.com/research/velocity/#uiPack)

But for make the same thing, you can't use "fadeIn" directly 
here we go

```
var $pen = jQuery('#pen');
    $arrow1 = jQuery('#arrow1');
    $psd = jQuery('#psd');
    $arrow2 = jQuery('#arrow2');
    $screen = jQuery('#screen');

var sequenceFade = [
    { e: $pen, p: {  opacity: 1 , display: "block"}, o:{duration :1500}},
    { e: $arrow1, p: {  opacity: 1 , display: "block"}, o: {duration: 1500}},
    { e: $psd, p: {  opacity: 1 , display: "block"}, o: {duration: 1500}},
    { e: $arrow2, p: {  opacity: 1 , display: "block"}, o: {duration: 1500}},
    { e: $screen, p: {  opacity: 1 , display: "block"}, o: {duration: 1500}}
  ];



$.Velocity.RunSequence(sequenceFade);
```